# Acquiring an access token in a sandbox

Tags: oauth2

I am using Postman to test the connected app I set up in a Salesforce sandbox environment. When I send the request to `https://xxx--partial.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token`, I get an `invalid_request` error with a description of "must use HTTP POST".

Here is the url with parameters: `https://xxx--partial.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=clientIdHere
&client_secret=clientSecretHere&username=myEmailAddress&password=myPassword&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

How can I obtain the access token with username/password in a sandbox?

Comment: test.salesforce.com or the xxx--partial.lightning.force.com domains should work. The error indicates that you need to use `POST` (as opposed to `GET`) to make the request. Do you have Postman set to make that request as a `POST`? Also, the username-password flow should generally be avoided.

Comment: I am using Post. I've read all the stuff about not using password, but JWT was failing completely. I was hoping to get password working then at least I would know I was hitting the correct endpoint. It is odd that changing the URL causes the post error even though I am posting.